# How to make blockUI work every time button is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I have a page that reads the excel file and load it onto a datatable which gets rendered inside a div. The user has to see the results of the uploaded file before they can continue with processing, this means I have two button events in one page, user has the ability to load a fresh copy of file from file-uploader, this means the block ui must be called whenever the user clicks the load button.

The problem I have is, the blockui only works for the first time, when I click on the button again with fresh copy of excel an error "blockUI is not a function" pops up. There was a suggestion to set the async inside ajax call to true, tried that but still not joy. My scripts are loaded using bundle config

I have a jquery method that reads the file and append the returned data into a div in a form of datatable, below is my jquery code

```
 $('#rateGroupsForm').submit(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault(); // stop the standard form submission
                $.blockUI();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ReadUploadedFile","Rates")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            $.unblockUI();
                            $('#rateGroupsDiv').empty();//remove all existing data before loading fresh one
                            $('#rateGroupsDiv').append(data);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, error, status) {
                        console.log(error, status);
                        $.unblockUI();
                    }
                });
         })
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, the "rateGroupsDiv" is getting loaded via a partial page which did not have any blockui script onto it, included the block ui script the partial page and all is well now